# Getting blank page using cURL twitter

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, twitter

I'm trying to add a twitter account using PHP w/Codeigniter framework.
I'm getting a blank page with no error not even in my log.  The bearer token is okay, I added it directly in the code for testing.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thank you

**Controller: manage.php**

```
   if($_POST['platform'] == 'twitter'):

  $request = curl_init();
    $bearer = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJ%xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/application/rate_limit_status.json');
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '.$bearer));
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = json_decode($content = curl_exec($request));
    curl_close($request);
    return($result);

    if($request == 0):
       $error = 'Sorry, rate limited';
    else:

        $account_data = @file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name='.$_POST['account_id'].'&include_entities=true');
        $account_data = json_decode($account_data);

    endif;

    if($account_data != false):
        $new_account = array(
            'id' => $account_data->screen_name,
            'username' => $account_data->screen_name,
            'name' => $account_data->name,
            'link' => 'https://twitter.com/'.$account_data->screen_name,
            'picture' => $account_data->profile_image_url,
            'platform' => 'twitter'
        );
    else:
        $error = "Account Not Found";
    endif;
```

**views: add.php**

```
   <?php

   if(isset($error)) echo "<p>".$error."</p>";

echo '<form action="/manage/add" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" style="margin-left:-15px; margin-top:-15px;">';

echo form_error('account_id');
echo '<strong>'.form_label('Account ID', 'account_id');
echo form_input('account_id', set_value('account_id', ''),'style="width: 288px;"');

    echo form_label('Platform', 'platform');
    echo form_dropdown('platform', $platforms, set_value('platform', $this->input->post('platform')));

$data = array('name' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Add Account', 'class' => 'submit');
echo form_submit($data);
  ?>

   <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**When I set it CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false I get.**

{"rate_limit_context":{"application":"N3KVVzpE8d0qapC6kJJSw"},"resources":{"lists":{"/lists/subscribers":{"limit":15,"remaining":15,"reset":1373460189},"/lists/list":{"limit":15,"remaining":15,"reset":1373460189},"/lists/memberships":{"limit":15,"remaining":15,"reset":1373460189},"/lists/ownerships":{"limit":15,"remaining":15,"reset":1373460189},"/lists/subscriptions":{"limit":15,"remaining":15,"reset":1373460189},"/lists/members":{"limit":15,"remaining":15,"reset":1373460189},"/lists/subscribers/show":{"limit":15,"remaining":15,"reset":1373460189},"/lists/statuses":{"limit":180,"remaining":180,"reset":1373460189},"/lists/show":{"limit":15,"remaining":15,"reset":1373460189},"/lists/members/show":{"limit":15,"remaining":15,"reset":1373460189}},"application":{"/application/rate_limit_status":{"limit":180,"remaining":169,"reset":1373459343}},"friendships":{"/friendships/show":{"limit":15,"remaining":15,"reset":1373460189}},"users":{"/users/profile_banner":{"limit":180,"remaining":180,"reset":1373460189},"/users/suggestions/:slug/members":{"limit":15,"remaining":15,"reset":1373460189},"/users/show/:id":{"limit":180,"remaining":180,"reset":1373460189},"/users/suggestions":{"limit":15,"remaining":15,"reset":1373460189},"/users/lookup":{"limit":60,"remaining":60,"reset":1373460189},"/users/suggestions/:slug":{"limit":15,"remaining":15,"reset":1373460189}},"followers":{"/followers/list":{"limit":30,"remaining":30,"reset":1373460189},"/followers/ids":{"limit":15,"remaining":15,"reset":1373460189}},"statuses":{"/statuses/show/:id":{"limit":180,"remaining":180,"reset":1373460189},"/statuses/oembed":{"limit":180,"remaining":180,"reset":1373460189},"/statuses/retweeters/ids":{"limit":60,"remaining":60,"reset":1373460189},"/statuses/user_timeline":{"limit":300,"remaining":300,"reset":1373460189},"/statuses/retweets/:id":{"limit":60,"remaining":60,"reset":1373460189}},"help":{"/help/privacy":{"limit":15,"remaining":15,"reset":1373460189},"/help/tos":{"limit":15,"remaining":15,"reset":1373460189},"/help/configuration":{"limit":15,"remaining":15,"reset":1373460189},"/help/languages":{"limit":15,"remaining":15,"reset":1373460189}},"friends":{"/friends/ids":{"limit":15,"remaining":15,"reset":1373460189},"/friends/list":{"limit":30,"remaining":30,"reset":1373460189}},"favorites":{"/favorites/list":{"limit":15,"remaining":15,"reset":1373460189}},"search":{"/search/tweets":{"limit":450,"remaining":450,"reset":1373460189}},"trends":{"/trends/available":{"limit":15,"remaining":15,"reset":1373460189},"/trends/place":{"limit":15,"remaining":15,"reset":1373460189},"/trends/closest":{"limit":15,"remaining":15,"reset":1373460189}}}}

Comment: Set `CURLOPT_HEADER => false,` and show us the info you are receiving.

Comment: I do not see anything new in your post.

Comment: See my results for CURLOPT_HEADER => false above.

Comment: Take a look at [this library](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php). You will be able to see how the headers are generated correctly here. Might as well just use that one file include, it's really simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

Your Authorization header looks wrong.  To do this kind of request you need to generate a signature.  There is more information on the [Twitter development site](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature)

I wrote a CodeIgniter library for making cURL requests to Twitter.  You may want to use it or just take bits of code from it.  The repository is [here](https://github.com/pattle/codeigniter-twitter-library)

Comment: I've already generated a signature.  I needed to get the bearer token as I'm using application-only authentication.  My dashboard has 312 users and I need to use this method on behalf of my users.  I was able to authenticate and get the bearer token, now I'm trying to add a new user.

Comment: If you want to add a user I think you are making your cURL request to the wrong URL

Comment: Actually it is getting the right user.  Let me add the add.php page form so you can see.

Comment: I changed  '$account_data = @file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name='.$_POST['account_id'].'&include_entities=true');
$account_data = json_decode($account_data);'. I get in my log file.  file_get_contents(http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=1560779942&amp;include_entities=true): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 410 Gone
 /Users/.../Sites/application/controllers/manage.php 106

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue.

```
  $request = curl_init();
    $bearer = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJ%2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0x0xxxxxx"; 
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name='.$account_id.'&include_entities=true');
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '.$bearer));
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $account_data = json_decode($file_get_contents = curl_exec($request)); 
    curl_close($request);
```